# How to change the functional insert-sort code to be tail recursive

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion, insertion-sort

Recently I implement  insert_sort algorithm by functional programming style,and it become more concise and declarative. the question is how to change it to be tail recursive, the code will throw exception if the size of list grows up to 10000.

```
def InsertSort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x::rest => 
       def insert (x: Int, sorted_xs:List[Int]) :List[Int] = sorted_xs match{
           case Nil => List(x)
           case y::ys => if  (x <= y) x::y::ys else y::insert(x,ys)
       }
       insert(x,InsertSort(rest))
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just introduced accumulators:

```
 @tailrec def InsertSort(xs: List[Int], acc: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] = 
  if (xs.nonEmpty) {
    val x :: rest = xs
    @tailrec 
    def insert(x: Int, sorted_xs: List[Int], acc: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] =
      if (sorted_xs.nonEmpty) { 
        val y :: ys = sorted_xs
        if (x <= y) acc ::: x :: y :: ys else insert(x,ys, acc :+ y)
      } else acc ::: List(x)
    InsertSort(rest, insert(x, acc))
  } else acc
```

`:::` and `:+` will take O(n) for the default `List` implementation, so it's better to use some more appropriate collection (like `ListBuffer`). You can also rewrite it with `foldLeft` instead of explicit recursion.

Faster option (with [`foldLeft`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala), without `:+`):

```
 @tailrec
 def insert(sorted_xs: List[Int], x: Int, acc: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] =
   if (sorted_xs.nonEmpty) { 
     val y::ys = sorted_xs
     if (x <= y) acc.reverse ::: x :: y :: ys else insert(ys, x, y :: acc)
   } else (x :: acc).reverse

 scala> List(1,5,3,6,9,6,7).foldLeft(List[Int]())(insert(_, _))
 res22: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9)
```

And finally with `span` (like in @roterl's answer, but `span` is a little faster - it traverses collection only until `> x` is found):

```
 def insert(sorted_xs: List[Int], x: Int) = if (sorted_xs.nonEmpty) { 
    val (smaller, larger) = sorted_xs.span(_ < x)
    smaller ::: x :: larger
 } else x :: Nil

 scala> List(1,5,3,6,9,6,7).foldLeft(List[Int]())(insert)
 res25: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9)
```

Comment: This is the only solution I could think of myself. But this code is barely readable. Especially if you compare it with the imperative alternative. I wonder if someone knows of a more elegant functional solution. Or is this a proof that the expression power of functional programming has its limitations?

Comment: i've added foldLeft option - looks pretty fine

Comment: Thanks. your foldleft edition is far more expressive but also far more abstractive.

Answer (score 2):

To make it tail recursive you should pass the sorted list as parameter instead of build it at the return value:

```
def InsertSort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def doSort(unsortXs: List[Int], sorted_xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    unsortXs match {
      case Nil => sorted_xs
      case x::rest => 
        val (smaller, larger) = sorted_xs.partition(_ < x)
        doSort(rest, smaller ::: x :: larger)
    }
  }
  doSort(xs, List())  
}
```

Comment: 'partition' just replaces the Insert method here. the @dk14 answer is more complete.